# How do we add apps in onelogin using python SDK?

Tags: api, get, onelogin

Is there any python sdk which helps in adding and/or configure applications on IDP(onelogin) side? Can someone point me to those APIs if they exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onelogin doesn't ( yet ) provide any API that manages applications, Python or otherwise. It is coming though and expected sometime this year.